# Creating a elisp function to convert URL to HTML link?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to create some sort of elisp function and bind it to a key that takes a URL, in one of two formats, and generate an HTML link element.

Here are the two input formats:

```
http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/
http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos|Safari Demos
```

Here are the two desired output values:

```
<a href="http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/">safaridemos</a>
<a href="http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/">Safari Demos</a>
```

Ideally, this would work on a region, but even if it only worked on one line, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 18):

Here's one way of doing it. This method works by having the user select the text that should be turned into a link and then replaces it.

```
;;; http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos|Safari Demos
;;; becomes <a href="http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos">Safari Demos</a>
;;; http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos|Safari Demos
;;; <a href="http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos">Safari Demos</a>

  (defun url-to-html-link(input)
  "Convert INPUT url into a html link. The link text will be the text after the last slash or you can end the url with a | and add text after that"
  (let ((split-on-| (split-string input "|"))
    (split-on-/ (split-string input "/"))
    (fmt-string "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>"))
    (if (> (length split-on-|) 1)
    (format fmt-string (first split-on-|) (second split-on-|))
      (format fmt-string input (first (last split-on-/))))))


(defun url-region-to-html-link(b e)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((link 
     (url-to-html-link (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))))
    (delete-region b e)
    (insert link)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c j") 'url-region-to-html-link)
```

EDIT: You can also use the first function in conjunction with `query-replace-regexp` to make an interactive command:

```
(defun query-replace-urls ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "http://.*"
                        (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote (url-to-html-link (match-string 0))))
                        nil
                        (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-beginning))
                        (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-end))))
```

Comment: you can borrow `query-replace-regexp` machinery by using the "\,(...)" form in the replacement.  See my edit.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps a better idea would be to use some snippet engine? For example, Yasnippet offers similar to abbreviations mechanism for filling in boilerplate text. I don't remember where exactly did I get the snippet below, but it would be trivial to come up with one like that yourself:

```
# contributor: Jimmy Wu <frozenthrone88 at gmail dot com>
# name: <a href="...">...</a>
# key: href
# --
<a href="$1">$2</a>
```

Yasnippet also allows you to place default values in the placeholders, eLisp code to query the user interactively while populating the snippet or reading some values from system state etc.